# Is there any way to prevent typeahead.js to inject inline styling?

Tags: css, twitter, typehead

I'm testing [Twitters typehead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) (with Bloodhound) as an alternative to jQuery autocomplete.

[As per documentation](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/):

> Custom Templates
>
> Custom templates give you full control over how suggestions get
>   rendered making it easy to customize the look and feel of your
>   typeahead.

So I use this:

```
$('#autocomplete-pm').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'Resources',
    display: 'value',
    source: resourcesData,
    templates: {
      empty: [
        '<div class="empty-message">',
        'Ingen resurser funnet',
        '</div>'
      ].join('\n'),
      suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div data-resource_id="{{resource_id}}"><strong>{{first_name}}</strong> – {{last_name}}</div>')
    }
  });
```

So I may have full controll over the output list, but the problem is that it wraps the enitre input in a `<span>` tag:

```
<span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
```

Is there a way to prevent this so it follows my sass styling?

Comment: Taking a quick look at the source code at github it looks like they add the inline css in places that you can't customize :(

Comment: I thought we were past this form of "intrution" when it comes to styling :( Not sure where to modify the source files either.

Comment: Check the `buildCss` function here for example: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/typeahead/www.js#L61

Comment: Ah, genious. I can work with this. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that this is not the only place there that affect the inline css...

Comment: I went crazy and it still works :-D Removed the hint box and the overflow div. I have no idea what the overflow div does.

Comment: Might be styling, might be older browsers support... I'm not sure

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but maybe my fixing could help somebody else. I added the following css style and problem solved:

```
.twitter-typeahead{
    display: flex !important;
}
```